# Are cascading checkbuttons possible in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried everything to try and create the menus shown below, yet I can not figure out how to cascade checkbuttons/checkboxes. I am new to Tkinter so I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I just want to know if the below photo is possible.

Thanks so much.

If this is a repeated question let me know, because I can't find any like it anywhere. Apologies for the low-quality photo!

[Desired menu output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs7PW.jpg)

Comment: Have you read the documentation and have you tried to code? If so, show us your code in order to get help for your question.

Comment: I just don't know how I could make a cascading menu also be a check button, so you could either check it or expand it to show another menu if that makes sense. I couldn't find any help in the documentation when I looked but I very well could be wrong.

Comment: _"I just don't know how I could make a cascading menu also be a check button"_ - Oh, that's not what I thought you were asking. No, you can't make something both a cascade menu _and_ a checkbutton.

Comment: Okay cool then I won’t waste anymore time on it! Thanks so much, I apologize for the confusing question!